# Оценка положения на основе сопоставления 2D и 3D координат точки

Tags: c++, opencv

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Решаю задачу ценки положения на основе соответствия двумерных и трехмерных координат точек.

Для этого у меня есть трехмерные коорднаты объекта (в его собственной системе координат), кватернион, описывающий поворот этого объекта в пространстве, а так же известно соответствия между трехмерными точками объекта и их проекциями на изображении.

Так понял, вот это формула связывает 3D и 2D координаты объекта. В этой формуле мне известно (u,v), фокусное расстояние f, r11...r33 (матрицу поворота получил из кватерниона). Неизвестен только вектор параллельного переноса t.

Вопрос, как найти вектор параллельного переноса t? Если решать систему, то получится система из двух уравнений с тремя неизвестными.

Так же снимок сделан стереокамерой, есть координаты точки на изображении с левой и правой камер. Через диспарантность и длину базовой линии могу вычислить координату z этой точки

Comment: Ну да, 3D координаты можно выудить только из стереопары. Снимок 2D эффективно уничножает информацию о третьей координате.

Comment: Эту систему нужно решать для нескольких точек сразу, не для одной. Тогда, зная фактическое расстояние между точками, и угловое расстояние по фотографии, можно найти расстояние от точек до камеры.

Comment: Я наверное не понимаю чего-то, звучит слишком просто? *"могу вычислить координату z этой точки"* - значит у вас есть трехмерные координаты точки в пространстве камеры, и преобразование из желаемой системы координат в пространство камеры. Находите обратное преобразование, и применяете его к координатам точки?